# How to add a UIScrollView to a xib based view

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, interface-builder

I am trying to create a xib based `UIView`.

I'd like to add a `UIScrollView` and then embed my content with in that, so that it scrolls when it does not fit and vice versa.

I have created the xib and added a scroll view, with anchors of 0 on top, left, bottom and right.

I am getting an error that the height and width is ambiguous however.

[image]

Historically I have always built these views in code, using something as simple as

```swift
...
      scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
      scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
      scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
      scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
...
      profilePictureImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),
      profilePictureImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 170),

      collectionView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
      collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profilePictureImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 6),
      collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
      collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor, constant: -32),
      collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
```

How do I create a full screen scroll view in a xib?

I have a seen a bunch of answers that suggest some random height of 1000, but that seems strange, especially as it does not require that approach in code.

I would like it to be full width and the height of all content inside it.

I did attempt to make xib base a `UIScrollView` instead but all my content was squashed to the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to embed scrollview in a UIView (with the same constraints), or you can use a *StackView* embedded in a scrollView.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35136217/4125225) a great explanation.

Answer (score 1):

One option to solve your issue is to disable the **Content Layout Guides**

[image]

See also: [Scrollable content size ambiguity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570660/how-to-fix-scrollable-content-size-ambiguity-in-xcode-11-ios-12-ios-13-usin)